# Invalid operands to binary & (have 'float *' and 'float')

Tags: c

I can't figure out what I need to do to get my code to work, I've tried a few things but the same error keeps occurring. I'm not sure how else to proceed, the main issue of the code appears to be converting the hours and minutes into only hours. I know this is a very basic question, but I'm a beginner and I can't seem to get a solution.

```
// freezer.c
// Estimates the temperature in a freezer given the elapsed time since a power failure.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
     float dec_time, // input - time in hours and minutes.
           temperature, // output - temperature in degrees celsius
           hours, // input for dec_time
          minutes; // input for dec_time 

     /* Get the time in hours and minutes */
     printf("hours and minutes since power failure: ");
     scanf("%lf%lf", &hours &minutes);

     /* Convert the time in hours and minutes into only hours in real number */
     dec_time = hours + (minutes / 60.0);

     // Using time via an equation to estimate the temperature
     temperature = ((4 * dec_time * dec_time) / (dec_time + 2)) - 20;

     // Display the temperature in degrees celsius
     printf("Temperature in freezer %9.2f.\n", temperature);

     return 0;
 }
```

Any explanation anyone can give to give me insight on this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: when I added the comma to the `scanf()` statement in the code on my computer, the primary compilation error in the title was resolved. I also changed the `%lf` to `%f`, but now when I key in a single digit to `a.out`, e.g. 3, the program does not compute until I key in `q`!.

Comment: Apart from the missing comma, `%lf` is the wrong format: It takes a `double *`, not a `float *`.

Comment: Please remove the line numbers. They make it impossible for us to try to compile your code.

Comment: The usual process if for you to create a post and people answers it - which you received 3 answers.  Since you have a new question,  Do not change the basics of this one.- create a new post. The new post should refer to this one, and state the new problem.  So revert this post's edit to its previous state (taking line number out is good).  Do not use SO with a repeatedly changing question.

Comment: Your code seeks two numbers.  When you type just `3`, the `scanf()` call is waiting for another number before it continues.  Further, on most systems, the program won't see any of the input until you hit the return key. When you add a `q` after the digit, the first conversion completes, the second conversion fails, and `scanf()` returns 1 (for one successful conversion) instead of the 2 you need.  You should always check the return from an input function to make sure it succeeded: `if (scanf("%f%f", &hours, &minutes) != 2) { …report that something went wrong and do not continue … }`.

Answer (score 3):

Change `scanf("%lf%lf", &hours &minutes)` to `scanf("%f%f", &hours, &minutes)`.  No `'l'`, [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene) add comma [@Anton Malyshev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32145187/2410359).

Also recommend to check result to see if it is 2. (2 fields successfully scanned).

```
if (2 != scanf("%f%f", &hours, &minutes)) {
  puts("Input error");
  exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("%lf%lf", &hours &minutes);
                      ^ comma needed
```

You missed a comma `,`.

Re-write as follows-

```
scanf("%f%f",&hours,&minutes);  // make sure you use only %f and not %lf
```

Comment: True, but not the only problem, even in that `scanf()` statement.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I missed the specifiers. I should edit it .

Answer (score 1):

You missed comma, that's how it should be: `scanf("%lf%lf", &hours, &minutes)`

Comment: so  scanf("%lf%lf", &hours, &minutes); will give me 2 hours and 30 minutes as 2.5 hours?

Comment: @PolluxAlRas No.Problem in your code was that it had syntax error.

Comment: @PolluxAlRas `scanf` is for reading input. The conversion happens in line 17, as the commend in line 16 says.